# Preview Desktop with Screenshot program VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I am just wondering. How can I adapt my code

```
        Dim Size As Rectangle
    Dim Capt As System.Drawing.Bitmap
    Dim Pic As Graphics

    Do While 1
        Size = Form2.Bounds
        Capt = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(Size.Width, Size.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb)
        Pic = Graphics.FromImage(Capt)
        Pic.CopyFromScreen(Size.X, Size.Y, 0, 0, Size.Size, CopyPixelOperation.MergeCopy)
        PictureBox1.Image = Capt
    Loop
```

To display a the picture from what a form sees. 
A clearer understanding would be
https://i.stack.imgur.com/euJmM.png

I have two forms, one has a picture box, the other is a transparent form, I want the picture box to show what is what the second form sees through it's transparent part (Can just be the whole form border and all). Then go on to save it to a file, I thought my code would auto update to where the second form has gone on the screen and auto fill the picture box, but apparently not.

Comment: i hope you are running this code in a separate thread, because this loop will prevent your form from responding if its in the form's class...

Comment: I am stupid, but not stupid enough to forget that. Everything works fine up until the fact I can't seem to get it to update to where I drag the second form that is the only problem I have so far.

Comment: i meant no offence. its just sometimes the small things that we miss which cause us the most headache later :)

Comment: I know you didn't mean anything by it, this problem has been doing my head in, and I bet it's a simple fix I can't see :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution for you, this achieves your desired result if i understood you correctly.

if you have any questions, feel free to ask:

```
Public Class Form2
    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.BackColor = Color.Magenta
        Me.TransparencyKey = Color.Magenta
    End Sub
End Class
```

```
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1
    Private ScreenShot As Thread
    Dim F2 As Form2
    Private Sub Capt_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Capt.Click
        CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
        F2 = New Form2
        F2.Show()
        ScreenShot = New Thread(AddressOf RefreshView)
        ScreenShot.IsBackground = True
        ScreenShot.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub RefreshView()
        Dim Size As Rectangle
        Dim Capt As System.Drawing.Bitmap
        Dim Pic As Graphics
        Do While 1
            Size = F2.RectangleToScreen(F2.ClientRectangle)
            Capt = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(Size.Width, Size.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb)
            Pic = Graphics.FromImage(Capt)
            Dim boundsLeft = Size.X
            Dim boundsTop = Size.Y
            Pic.CopyFromScreen(boundsLeft, boundsTop, 0, 0, Size.Size, CopyPixelOperation.MergeCopy)
            pictureBox1.Image = Capt
        Loop
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Nope, same issue, it only shows where the box started and won't update to follow the second box around the screen, either I'm doing it wrong or something, but I don't know.
http://pastebin.com/CFnX68AC is my code from Form1.vb Please don't yell about cross threaded calls ;-; 
http://pastebin.com/6iiNCaaJ
is form2

Comment: This is in fact a cross threading issue. The form's controls should only be updated from the form's creating thread, and this is why i used a timer in my example. If you want to use a new thread, you need to wrap your `refreshview()` sub with another sub `thread_main()` which will run on the new thread, and inside this `thread_main()` you need to invoke `refreshview()` on the Form1's thread. I don't remember the exact syntax, something with `Form1.BeginInvoke()` , ill write an example later when i get to a computer.

Comment: Ah damn, I was afraid that would become an issue :/ only problem is I know basics of C++ and don't know how to pass form controls to a sub function on Visual Basic, and thought I could bypass it. Oh well. Thanks for taking the time to.

Comment: Don't worry this is no big deal, do a quick research on delegates, and when i get to a pc ill update my answer. U only need like 4 extra lines of code to make it work.

Comment: @Jalomba alright i tested your code and it seems the problem was not cross thread operations. although cross thread on forms should be avoided anyway, the problem was that you needed to instantiate form2 and calculate the bounds of the instance. ill update my answer.